# How to add "Read more " to opera news to Link your website?

Tags: html

I have been adding news to opera news . But the thing is , it only getting reading  view, all the internal links been removed and no option or link to my website. I have seen others website have option at last called "read more " which is link to rest of the article. Please help me how to add